# How to read multiple images from two different folders one by one using python?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I am new to python and in a learning stage.
I am trying to read multiple images from two different folders in a similar order.
Each folder contains 147 images. In one folder there is thermal image (FLIR1271) and second folder contains visible RGB image (FLIR1272) corresponding to thermal image.
My task is to read and display images one by one from each folder at the same time. The code should be written in such a way that FLIR1271 should be read first thermal image folder and then go to next folder and read it's corresponding visible image FLIR1272. This process should be applied on rest of the 146 images. I tried something given below:

```
for i in range(0,10):
thermalimages = [] #list of image filenames
  thermal_dir_path = '/content/Infrared_Thermal_Termination_Images'
  thermaldirFiles = os.listdir(thermal_dir_path) #list of directory files
  thermaldirFiles.sort() #good initial sort but doesnt sort numerically very well
  #*sorted(dirFiles) #sort numerically in ascending order
  for files in thermaldirFiles: 
    if '.jpg' in files:
      thermalimages.append(files)
  print (thermalimages)

  visibleimages = [] #list of image filenames
  visible_dir_path = '/content/Visible_Termination_Images'
  visibledirFiles = os.listdir(visible_dir_path) #list of directory files
  visibledirFiles.sort() #good initial sort but doesnt sort numerically very well
  #*sorted(dirFiles) #sort numerically in ascending order
  for files in visibledirFiles: 
    if '.jpg' in files:
      visibleimages.append(files)
  print (visibleimages)
```

Unfortunately, it's giving unexpected output:

['FLIR1271.jpg', 'FLIR1273.jpg', 'FLIR1281.jpg', 'FLIR1289.jpg', 'FLIR1293.jpg', 'FLIR1337.jpg', 'FLIR1525.jpg', 'FLIR1527.jpg', 'FLIR1529.jpg', 'FLIR1531.jpg', 'FLIR1703.jpg', 'FLIR1711.jpg', 'FLIR1713.jpg', 'FLIR1715.jpg', 'FLIR1719.jpg', 'FLIR1721.jpg', 'FLIR1723.jpg', 'FLIR1725.jpg', 'FLIR1737.jpg', 'FLIR1739.jpg', 'FLIR1781.jpg', 'FLIR1783.jpg', 'FLIR1787.jpg', 'FLIR1789.jpg', 'FLIR1791.jpg', 'FLIR1793.jpg', 'FLIR1795.jpg', 'FLIR1809.jpg', 'FLIR1811.jpg', 'FLIR1813.jpg', 'FLIR1815.jpg', 'FLIR1817.jpg', 'FLIR1819.jpg', 'FLIR1821.jpg', 'FLIR1833.jpg', 'FLIR1835.jpg', 'FLIR1839.jpg', 'FLIR1841.jpg', 'FLIR1843.jpg', 'FLIR1847.jpg', 'FLIR1859.jpg', 'FLIR1861.jpg', 'FLIR1871.jpg', 'FLIR1887.jpg', 'FLIR1889.jpg', 'FLIR1891.jpg', 'FLIR1893.jpg', 'FLIR1895.jpg', 'FLIR1961.jpg', 'FLIR1963.jpg', 'FLIR1965.jpg', 'FLIR1967.jpg', 'FLIR1969.jpg', 'FLIR1971.jpg', 'FLIR1973.jpg', 'FLIR1975.jpg', 'FLIR1977.jpg', 'FLIR1979.jpg', 'FLIR1987.jpg', 'FLIR1989.jpg', 'FLIR1991.jpg', 'FLIR1993.jpg', 'FLIR1995.jpg', 'FLIR1997.jpg', 'FLIR1999.jpg', 'FLIR2001.jpg', 'FLIR2003.jpg', 'FLIR2005.jpg', 'FLIR2007.jpg', 'FLIR2009.jpg', 'FLIR2011.jpg', 'FLIR2013.jpg', 'FLIR2015.jpg', 'FLIR2017.jpg', 'FLIR2019.jpg', 'FLIR2021.jpg', 'FLIR2023.jpg', 'FLIR2025.jpg', 'FLIR2027.jpg', 'FLIR2031.jpg', 'FLIR2033.jpg', 'FLIR2035.jpg', 'FLIR2037.jpg', 'FLIR2039.jpg', 'FLIR2041.jpg', 'FLIR2043.jpg', 'FLIR2045.jpg', 'FLIR2047.jpg', 'FLIR2049.jpg', 'FLIR2051.jpg', 'FLIR2053.jpg', 'FLIR2055.jpg', 'FLIR2057.jpg', 'FLIR2059.jpg', 'FLIR2061.jpg', 'FLIR2063.jpg', 'FLIR2065.jpg', 'FLIR2067.jpg', 'FLIR2069.jpg', 'FLIR2071.jpg', 'FLIR2073.jpg', 'FLIR2075.jpg', 'FLIR2077.jpg', 'FLIR2079.jpg', 'FLIR2081.jpg', 'FLIR2083.jpg', 'FLIR2085.jpg', 'FLIR2097.jpg', 'FLIR2099.jpg', 'FLIR2101.jpg', 'FLIR2103.jpg', 'FLIR2105.jpg', 'FLIR2107.jpg', 'FLIR2111.jpg', 'FLIR2113.jpg', 'FLIR2115.jpg', 'FLIR2117.jpg', 'FLIR2131.jpg', 'FLIR2133.jpg', 'FLIR2135.jpg', 'FLIR2137.jpg', 'FLIR2139.jpg', 'FLIR2141.jpg', 'FLIR2143.jpg', 'FLIR2145.jpg', 'FLIR2147.jpg', 'FLIR2149.jpg', 'FLIR2151.jpg', 'FLIR2153.jpg', 'FLIR2155.jpg', 'FLIR2157.jpg', 'FLIR2167.jpg', 'FLIR2169.jpg', 'FLIR2171.jpg', 'FLIR2173.jpg', 'FLIR2175.jpg', 'FLIR2177.jpg', 'FLIR2179.jpg', 'FLIR2181.jpg', 'FLIR2183.jpg', 'FLIR2185.jpg', 'FLIR2187.jpg', 'FLIR2189.jpg', 'FLIR2191.jpg', 'FLIR2193.jpg', 'FLIR2195.jpg', 'FLIR2197.jpg']

Comment: It's not clear how this is wrong or what the expected output should be. Is the second image always one higher than the corresponding first one?

Comment: In this case,  the code should work like: read one thermal image (FLIR1271) from a Thermal Images folder and move to Visible Images folder to read Visible image (FLIR1272) and do it for rest of the images. In the both the folders, images are in a sequence.  Thermal images are like FLIR1271, FLIR1273, FLIR1281, FLIR1289, FLIR1293.... (odd numbers) and Visible images are like FLIR1272, FLIR1274, FLIR1282, FLIR1290, FLIR1294..... (even numbers)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it. Perhaps also review the guidance for providing a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although in your case, (you have fixed length strings, the prefix is also the same) you *might* get the expected output after sorting, it's better not to compare/sort numbers when they are strings. Always pay attention to how you're sorting the strings containing numbers. i.e `"8"` is bigger than `"12"`

And from your explanation about "one by one from each folder at the same time" you need to zip those lists containing file names and iterate through them like:

```py
thermal_files = [f"FLIR127{i}" for i in range(1, 6, 2)]
thermal_files.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.removeprefix("FLIR")))

RGB_files = [f"FLIR127{i}" for i in range(2, 7, 2)]
RGB_files.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.removeprefix("FLIR")))

print(thermal_files)
print(RGB_files)

for thermal, rgb in zip(thermal_files, RGB_files):
    print(f"Do something with thermal: {thermal}")
    print(f"Do something with RGB: {rgb}")
    print("-----------------------------------")
```

output:

```
['FLIR1271', 'FLIR1273', 'FLIR1275']
['FLIR1272', 'FLIR1274', 'FLIR1276']
Do something with thermal: FLIR1271
Do something with RGB: FLIR1272
-----------------------------------
Do something with thermal: FLIR1273
Do something with RGB: FLIR1274
-----------------------------------
Do something with thermal: FLIR1275
Do something with RGB: FLIR1276
-----------------------------------
```

**Note**: Don't count on the order of the returned list from [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> The list is in arbitrary order.

**Note**: `if '.jpg' in files:` is not a correct way to check the file's extension in general. Use `.endswith()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing the solution. Unfortunately, I am getting below error :

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'

Comment: Also,  I am looking for a process like below:

In this case,  the code should work like: read one thermal image (FLIR1271) from a Thermal Images folder and move to Visible Images folder to read Visible image (FLIR1272) and do it for rest of the images. In the both the folders, images are in a sequence.  Thermal images are like FLIR1271, FLIR1273, FLIR1281, FLIR1289, FLIR1293.... (odd numbers) and Visible images are like FLIR1272, FLIR1274, FLIR1282, FLIR1290, FLIR1294..... (even numbers)

Comment: @Saloni_C The solution I provided for you iterates just like you stated. In every iteration you have access to both thermal and rgb images. Instead of the print statements you can call you desired functions.

Comment: I understood, but these images should come from the respective folders. How should I integrate that into the solution given by you?

Comment: @Saloni_C I just simulated your `thermaldirFiles` and `visibledirFiles` lists so that the code can be executable. You already have those two, sort them based on the integer part and then `zip()` them.

Comment: Okay. I am trying to execute the solution. But getting error in 'removeprefix'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'

Comment: @Saloni_C It's a new feature in Python 3.9, which version are you using ?

Comment: @Saloni_C you can use `thermal_files.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[4:]))` instead. (length of `"FLIR"`)

Comment: Great. It's working. Not getting 'removefix' error anymore and getting exactly the same output given above in your solution.